# How to interpret/"understand with hands" the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-na}\ne \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-na}dn$?

Tags: integration

Let's consider that $a$ is positive quantity.

We have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-na}=\frac{1}{1-e^{-a}}$.

If we move to a continuous sum, we have : $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-na}dn=1/a$.

How to interpret the fact that two results are different ?

(I have in mind Planck demonstration of black body spectrum where he had the idea to use a discrete sum instead of a continuous sum)

Comment: Why should they be the same? The transition from a sum to an integral requires the spacing to be infinitesimal, whereas the spacing in $n$ is by one’s. (That is, $\Delta n=1$.) The sum and integral may be approximately the same but they aren’t identical. For details on this approximation, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maclaurin_formula.

Comment: All right thank you. This was very important to me, to understand the Planck law demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a$ is always positive. Therefore, $e^{-na}$ is strictly decreasing with respect to $n$. It follows that $\int\limits_i^{i + 1} e^{-na} dn < e^{-ia}$.

Therefore, we have

$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-na} dn = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{\infty} \int\limits_i^{i + 1} e^{-na} dn < \sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty e^{-ia} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty e^{-na}$